# HDInsight: Spark - how to upload a file?

Tags: azure-hdinsight

I have an new HDInisght:Spark cluster that I spun up
I want to upload a file via AMbari portal but I don't see the HDFS option:

[image]

What am I missing?  How can I get my .csv up to the server so I can start using it in the Python notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDInsight clusters do not work off local HDFS. They use Azure Blob Storage instead. So upload to the storage account that got attached to the cluster during its creation.

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage